# Cannot inject @Test annotated Method [Entertheuapp] with [class java.lang.String, class java.lang.String]

Tags: selenium

Previously it was running without any error in my old system but now it's showing a error in new system

Comment: Maybe you should start from checking what's different in your old vs new system? We can't of course know that, because you didn't tell us anything what you have done.

Comment: Actually i created the hybrid frame work for the project with base class,one subclass,.property file and excel but i have changed the path,jar based on the new system

Comment: That should be part of your question, and also of course all the things you have done / checked that are not the issue.